# ruby string for route issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, routes

I am going to save route to ruby string.
And I met this issue.

```
b = B.new
b.str = "/json.log"
puts b.str
b.save

result:

NULL
```

And if I change the str field in navicat it shows like this.

```
puts b.str
```

result:

```
public/uploads/B/src/1/json.log
```

Is there anyone who can help me with ruby string and route?

Comment: Try `puts b.errors`. I think you didn't pass modal validation, so record is not saved.

Comment: `puts b.errors` result `<#ActiveModel:Errors:0x007fa7a262fb78>`

Comment: Corrected, try `puts b.errors.inspect`.

Comment: There's no details error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a following code.

```
mount_uploader :str, JsonUploader
```

It converted `'/json.log'` to `null` in table
And converted `'/json.log'` in table to `'public/uploads/B/src/1/json.log'`

Result: with mount_uploader you can't set the route as string.